# Настройка тестирования в среде idea hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

Tags: java, junit

написал класс и захотел создать тест junit4 но почему то среда мне импортирует:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

в результате у меня зачёркивается слово assertThat

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

приходится стирать строку

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

и импортировать

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

и тогда всё норм, с чем это связано? как мне настроить чтобы импорт был автоматический?

использую сборку maven
прикладываю pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.akaleganov</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateSpring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>${basedir}/db/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <url>${db.url}</url>
                    <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                    <username>${db.username}</username>
                    <password>${db.password}</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>avito</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <db.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/avito</db.url>
                <db.username>postgres</db.username>
                <db.password/>
                <db.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</db.driver>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Hibernate START-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-beta-2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Hibernate END-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: А что так и не работает?

Comment: а почему зачёркивает assertThat